# Tomcat app is loading all of it's code from a jar - where does it say to use that jar?

Tags: java, tomcat

This Java web-app I am using that other developers wrote is structured in the standard way. However, `.class` files are not located under `WEB-INF/classes` they are instead grouped together in a .jar and stored under `WEB-INF/lib/myapp.jar`.

The issue is that I can't find where the program tells Tomcat to load `myapp.jar` for the class files. The app is working fine, but how does it know to load that `myapp.jar`?

I've tried `grep`ping my way through pretty much all conf files (in Tomcat and inside the app), and nowhere I can reference this `myapp.jar` file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following from what @nhnb said, [here](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/class-loader-howto.html)'s an explanation from Apache on how Tomcat's classLoader works.

> **WebappX** - A class loader is created for each web application that
>   is deployed in a single Tomcat 6
>   instance. All unpacked classes and
>   resources in the */WEB-INF/classes*
>   directory of your web application
>   archive, plus classes and resources in
>   JAR files under the */WEB-INF/lib*
>   directory of your web application
>   archive, are made visible to the
>   containing web application, but to no
>   others.

So if you want to reference `myApp.jar` you must be under the same class loader of that webapp, which essentially means that you have to be in the same webapp.

Alternatively, load your jar in `TOMCAT_HOME/lib` (Tomcat 6 and higher) or `TOMCAT_HOME/common/lib`. All jars found there are visible to all class loaders.

Comment: As was mentioned by @sthohnroe, this is default behavour for a servlet container.  It is not Tomcat specific.

Answer (score 3):

Tomcat simply loads all .jar files in the WEB-INF/lib folder.

Answer (score 2):

That is actually the default behavior for a Servlet Container.